# Unable to click on items in modal window

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, mouseevent, pointer-events

I've been trying to fix a problem with my modal window i'm using.

http://dev.ikov.org/store/index.php

When you go to the store, then press weapons on the right hand side, then select the item, the modal window pops up. However, i cant highlight the text or select the textbox or press the button.

**HTML**

```
<div id="ags" class="modalDialog2">  <!-- overlay -->
  <div id="storeboxitem"> <!-- modal box -->
    <div id="storeboxlight">
        <!-- content goes here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.modalDialog2 {
  position: fixed!important;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0!important;
  right: 0!important;
  bottom: 0!important;
  left: 0!important;
  background: #000!important;
  z-index: 999!important;
  opacity: 0!important;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#storeboxitem {
  display: block!important;
  background: url(imgs/contentboxbg.png)!important;
  border: 1px solid #070810!important;
  position: relative!important;
  width: 575px!important;
  height: 500px!important;
  z-index: 9999!important;
}

#storeboxlight {
  display: block!important;
  background: url(imgs/lightbg.png) no-repeat!important;
  z-index: 9999!important;
  border-top: 1px solid #13182c;
  margin: auto!important;
  width: 575px!important;
  height: 100%!important;
}
```

I've also noticed that the items in the back can be clicked, so i thought it might be a problem with the z-index, so i then tried changing that but nothing worked.

Comment: That's because the popup content is an image. You cannot select the text that the image displays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have used [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) for the `.modalDialog2` element which is the modal's container.

`pointer-events: none;` prevents the element and its descendants<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)</sup> from being targeted by mouse events.

Hence, simply remove that:

```css
.modalDialog2 {
    /* pointer-events: none; */
}
```

You can also override the pointer event property for the descendants by using the `auto` value. For instance, use `pointer-events: auto;` on `#storeboxitem` element (The modal box) or another elements.

```css
#storeboxitem { /* A child element */
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

<sub>[MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) Mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have `pointer-events` set to some other value</sub>

Comment: I din't ask this question but it kept bugging me. Thank you for teaching me something new.

Comment: @user3344398 Don't mention it :)

Answer (score 0):

Please delete `pointer-event: none` in `.modalDialog2`